# How to manage configuration files for embedded system with a custom config for each program?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, embedded, configuration-management

Our product is an embedded system, and each physical product has its own configuration, there are ~300 of them to manage. Most systems are offline.

When it comes to updating them, there can be major config management issue.

Ideally, we would like a easy to use system where you can centrally store all application config files and keep a history of them.
(basically a simple to use version control system with upload, instant commit, and history diff)

Comment: What is that you asking?

Comment: Try GitHub or BitBucket

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic on SO. Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git of course for that purpose.

Add all your files to git and start to manage them.

If you have shared resources you can use branches to store them.
Git also support siff, patches and almost anything else that you will need for managing versions of files.

Keep in mind that git is not a good place to store binary files. If you need binary files take a look on this project:

[Git-fls](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

[image]